# Recyclerview - Notifydatachange() does not work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a tabbed activty with 4 tabs. Each tab has fragment and fragmentlayout has Recycler View with RelativeLayout. The first time data is read from DB , recycler view displays the data. When the SqlLite Db is updated(in BroadcastReeiver) , i want to get RecyclerView with updated Data. Notifydata change does not work

```
//BroadcastReceiver : onReceive
        var allFragment = AllCallsFragment()

        var allFragmentActivity = allFragment.instance()
        if (allFragmentActivity != null) {
            allFragmentActivity.getCallDetails()

        }

//AllCallFragment -
  public fun getCallDetails(){
        var db = CallLogDatabase(myActivity)
        displayList = db.queryDatabase("All")

        allCallList.addAll(displayList)
        allCallAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to get updated data from db ?

Comment: How do you set `allCallList` to `allCallAdapter`? Do you use a copy within the adapter?

Comment: allCallAdapter = AllCallAdapter(displayList , myActivity as Context)

Comment: My adapter Class is defined : class AllCallAdapter(_allCallList: ArrayList<CallDetails>?, _context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AllCallAdapter.MyViewHolder>()

Comment: and  init {
        this.mContext = _context
        this.allCallList = _allCallList
    }

Comment: isn't querydatabase an async operation?

Comment: querydatabase is not async...but when i add to the DB ie save DB is async

Comment: i removed asynctask all togetther. it is adding to the db but not retrieving

Comment: @Piyush : it updates the DB but does not fetch on queryDatabase